# Test ViewModel with Jetpack Compose e compose state

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm getting the following error in my ViewModel test, it's pretty clear, but I can't figure out why.

```
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method androidx.paging.CachedPagingDataKt.cachedIn, parameter <this>
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method androidx.paging.CachedPagingDataKt.cachedIn, parameter <this>
```

my test class

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MoviePopularViewModelTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var getPopularMoviesUseCase: GetPopularMoviesUseCase

    private lateinit var moviePopularViewModel: MoviePopularViewModel

    private val pagingDataMovies = PagingData.from(
        listOf(
            Movie(
                id = 1,
                title = "Avengers",
                voteAverage = 7.1,
                imageUrl = "Url"
            ),
            Movie(
                id = 2,
                title = "Iron Men",
                voteAverage = 7.9,
                imageUrl = "Url"
            )
        )
    )

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        moviePopularViewModel = MoviePopularViewModel(getPopularMoviesUseCase)
    }

     @Test
    fun `should validate the paging data object values when calling moviesPagingData`() = runTest {
      
     whenever(getPopularMoviesUseCase.invoke()).thenReturn(
            flowOf(pagingDataMovies)
        )

      val pagingData = pagingDataMovies
      val result = moviePopularViewModel.uiState.results.first()

     result.map { resultMovie ->
            pagingData.map { pagingData ->
                assertThat(pagingData.title).isEqualTo(resultMovie.title)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

ViewModel code:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MoviePopularViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getPopularMoviesUseCase: GetPopularMoviesUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

  var uiState by mutableStateOf(MoviePopularState())
        private set

  init {
        val movies = getPopularMoviesUseCase.invoke()
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        uiState = uiState.copy(results = movies)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me where is the weak point in my code?

The dependencies are correct, I tried other ways to mock GetPopularMoviesUseCase, but without success

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same issue